# Problems with a PHP function involving a switch statement

Tags: php, switch-statement

I'm getting a syntax error, "unexpected ':' on line 38", I can't figure it out:

```
public static function clearTasks($type){
    $con = taskDB::connectDB();

    switch ($type){
        /* line 38: */
        case: 'completed':
            $type='=1';
            break;
        case: 'failed':
            $type='=0';
            break;
        case: 'pending':
            $type='is null';
            break;
        case: 'all':
            $type='=1 or completed=0 or is null';
            break;
    }
    $result = $con->query("DELETE FROM taskage WHERE completed".$type);
    $con->close();  
}
```

Can anyone tell me why this is happening? Thanks!

Comment: // Bad: `case: 'completed':`; // Correct: `case 'completed':`  See the PHP doc for details: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

Answer (score 3):

There is no `:` after `case`

```
case: 'completed':
```

should be

```
case 'completed':
```

Comment: Oh man! I have no idea how I missed that. Thank you! Will mark correct once the time limit is up.